# Configuring Netbeans for C++ code with options

Tags: c++, ubuntu, netbeans

I can compile a C++ code from ubuntu terminal with lapack library as

```
$g++ -lstdc++ -o  fast_solver fast_solver.cpp -llapack
```

My question is if I want to use Netbeans IDE to compile the same code how do I configure Netbeans? More specifically, how do I ask Netbeans to compile with `-lstdc++` and `-llapack` options?

Thank you in advance.

Best,
Geek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need (including compilers) comes in that NetBeans IDE package.

I would suggest that you read [this](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/quickstart.html) guide which will show you how to create a new project and run code.

Its pretty easy.

In NetBeans IDE press **F1** for more documentation.

Comment: Actually I have gone through the page you mentioned  already and found very useful. However I was confused about how to tell netbeans to use `-llapack` while compiling.

Comment: I figured out that doing the following would work, `Project properties` -> `Build` -> `linker` -> `Compilation line` -> `-llapack`